# Python / Pandas - Dynamically calculate yearly ratios in a dataframe with year column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df:

     Co_Name  . 2014 Revenues . Address . 2012 Profits . 2014 Profits...
1 .  Apple      1231            Gjud St   20             23          ...
2 .  Orange     84894           Uinjs St  712            313         ...
3 .  Squirrel   9192            Iusaa St  4312           123         ...
...
```

For example: '2014 Revenues' represent the Revenues that a certain company had in the year of 2014.

I need to calculate different ratios making equations with values from the same year. For example, I need to calculate the profit margin from 2014, that is to say:

```
df['2014 ProfitMg'] = df['2014 Profits']/df['2014 Revenues']
```

However, I have a lot of years and a lot of ratios to take out of this dataframe (huge dataframe) so I would like to make that in a dynamic and pythonic way. I want to say: "Mr Python, please calculate Profits/Revenues for the columns named 'Profits' and 'Revenues' that start with the same 4 characters string" or something like that.

It should look like this:

```
     Co_Name  . 2014 Revenues . Address . 2012 Profits . 2014 Profits . 2014 ProfitMg  ...
1 .  Apple      1231            Gjud St   20             23             0.019
2 .  Orange     84894           Uinjs St  712            313            0.008
3 .  Squirrel   9192            Iusaa St  4312           123            0.0133
...
```

Can someone help on making this in a dynamic way instead of a `df['2014 ProfitMg'] = df['2014 Profits']/df['2014 Revenues']`?

Comment: Consider reshaping your data so that years are a column.  Then `groupby()` `Co_name` and `year`, and apply your function (e.g. `profit / revenue`) to each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can find the matching columns and apply the formula to them:

```
import re
years = [re.findall(r"(\d{4})\sRevenues", col) for col in df.columns]
for year in years:
    if year:
        df['{} ProfitMg'.format(year[0])] = df['{} Profits'.format(year[0])]\
                                       / df['{} Revenues'.format(year[0])]
```

This solution assumes that for each "Revenues" column there is a matching "Profits" column. If not, get the set of "Profit" years and the set of "Revenues" years and take their intersection.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# create some data
profit_nm = ['. '+str(i)+' Profits' for i in range(1951,2051)]
revenue_nm = ['. '+str(i)+' Revenues' for i in range(1951,2051)]
column_nm = profit_nm+revenue_nm
column_nm.sort()
data = np.asarray(np.random.randint(100,1000,size=(1000,200)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=column_nm)

# function that will return the ratios
def func(pd_series):
    year = pd_series.name[:6]
    ret =  df.loc[:,year+' Profits']/df.loc[:,year+' Revenues']
    return ret

# extract names of profit columns from dataframe
profit_cols = [i for i in df.columns.tolist() if i.find(' Profits')!=-1]
#  get ratios and store in df
df2 = df.loc[:,profit_cols].apply(func, axis=0)
# change column names before joining as column names are same in df and df2
df2.columns = [year[:6]+' PftPct' for year in profit_cols]
df = df.join(df2)
```